# Display a SVG around an image on hover

Tags: javascript, css

So I would like to add shape around img when it is hover.

My img have border-radius 50% but shape that will shown - will be hexagon (SVG).

Can I do it, only in CSS? Or I need to use JS?

Comment: have you tried anything  ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: TBH - I thought about something like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObZyej
(this is only for example) but I can put there SVG image...

Answer (score 0):

You can have SVG hexagon image as background of a div and you can make it hide initially, and you can show your image in that div, and upon hover event of your image you can show that hexagon image stated in parent div.

You can have css something like below :

```css
.parent-div .svg-img{
display:hidden;
}

.child-img:hover .child-img:parent img{
display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use a background where stands the svg:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  float:left;
  pointer-events:none;/* to trigger events only on img:hover */
}
img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  pointer-events:auto;/* catch mouse events so are parents seeing it too */
}
span:hover,
span +img:hover {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iY29sb3ItZmlsbCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMwMCIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiPg0KICANCiAgPHBvbHlnb24gY2xhc3M9ImhleCIgcG9pbnRzPSIzMDAsMTUwIDIyNSwyODAgNzUsMjgwIDAsMTUwIDc1LDIwIDIyNSwyMCI+PC9wb2x5Z29uPg0KICANCjwvc3ZnPg==);
}
span + img {
  padding: 50px;/* those extra 50px catch hover too */
  
}
```

```html
<span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200&text=span-img"/></span>

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200&text=img-alone" />
```

Comment: Ok, but how did you get this SVG code? I mean I have SVG in HTML file not as an file on disc.

Comment: @Damian this is why i used data to insert image within the css file. SVG inside the HTML document cannot be used as a background else where (#mysvg do not work) See tools online such as : http://boazsender.github.io/datauri/ to turn a file into a data uri